# Testing Javascript floating point rounding mode conformance

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, cross-browser, standards-compliance

ECMA **requires** conformable implementors to perform “[round to nearest, ties to even](http://archive.is/TiIoC#selection-124247.105-124247.135)” for <Number> plus [[cp](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-applying-the-additive-operators-to-numbers)], minus [[cp](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-subtraction-operator-minus)], times [[cp](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-applying-the-mul-operator)], divide [[cp](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-applying-the-div-operator)], and mod [[cp](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-applying-the-mod-operator)].

What's a good Javascript test code to determine conformance?